# Rails 4 | Properly creating and saving in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a messaging system of sorts.  It's part of a bigger overall system in Rails 4.
Anyway, to setup my question briefly I have users who can both send and receive messages.  So in my "new" users' view I send a parameter [:receiver_id] to the message controller when creating a new message.

My question is how do I get the @send_to variable down to the create action properly.  I had to send it into the messages@new action via the receiver_id from the users' view.  Do I store it as a message parameter somehow or make it a hidden parameter?

Here is my messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
    #this :receiver_id is being sent from the show view in the user controller / view
    #it is being used to pass a parameter
    @send_to = User.find(params[:receiver_id])
    @message.sender = current_user
    @message.receiver = @send_to
    
    #the form_for should save the message with the RESTful action of create method in this controller
  end
  
  def create
    debugger
    @messasge = Message.create!(message_params)
    redirect_to users_path
  end
  
  def index
    @messages = current_user.messages
  end
  
  def sent
    @messages = current_user.messages
  end
  
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit!
  end
end
```

I know from rails routing mostly about RESTful actions, and yes I have read over the routing guide again before writing this.

## EDIT:

I have moved these two lines down into the create function.  The @send_to needs the :receiver_id though.

```
@message.sender = current_user
@message.receiver = @send_to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should implement an asynchronous request for sending messages, cause it might be annoying for system users to redirect to another page just to send a message. From the above snippets it is not known (the logic).
2. Having an asynchronous request, which would serve a dialog with new message form, next step is just to send form data to `messages#create` action. I assume that user, while fulfilling form data, can select somehow message recipient.
3. Action `new` does not need to know who is the message receiver.
4. Don't use `Message.create!` (with `!`) because it will raise an exception if creation fails. Use `save` instead and handle case if it would fail,

e.g:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new params[:message]
  @message.save

  respond_to do |f|
    f.json do
      render :json => {:success => @message.persisted?, :message => @message}.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The whole idea is after sending a message, they don't need to send the message anymore.  Does it still need to be asynchronous?  How do I handle the .save case if it fails?

Comment: Skip point 1 then and apply the rest. Within `new` action render message form and with `create` action persist the user message. I don't get the idea of having `@send_to` in `new` action.

Comment: The whole idea is having the association of users and messages.  Each message has a sender and receiver.  I need to know who is which so in the inbox I can have it to only those they got sent to, and in the outbox only those which they sent.  But that means each message belongs to two different unique users.

Comment: So, given that each message belongs_to 2 different users, a sender and receiver, the send_to is how I keep track of who am I sending it to, so when I create the message I can attribute it to them.  This is given by the id of who I am viewing which I passed to the Messages controller.  That's why it's in the new action, but I really need to save this information with the message so somehow it has to get to the create action because I need it in the DB.

Comment: Well, I still don't know all the logic, but let's skip that. I assume you have some form somewhere while sending that message. Just add a hidden field, e.g `<%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, :value => f.object.receiver_id %>` so that you can keep `receiver_id` and send it further to `messages#create`.

Comment: Good assumption, yes I do.  So I have to pass it along as a hidden field.  ok, thanks!  I really appreciate it!  Also, is respond_to an asynchronous event used to handle it?